# Windows Remote Desktop throws "Internal error" when connecting from a certain IP

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

Since a few days ago I have been unable to connect to a certain server via MSTSC only from one specific IP address.

I had one PC (Win 7) with a static IP address (let's say 192.168.1.99) which, out of the blue, started throwing a generic "Internal error" when trying to RDP to one certain server, which is out of the domain on the DMZ on a different network (let's say 192.168.2.99).

I had just received a new PC with Windows 10, which I configured to be my new workstation, hence I turned the old PC's address into dynamic IP and switched the new PC to the static address I used before (due to various reasons, mainly shared folders via IP)
When the new Win10 PC was freshly configured, I could RDP to said server, but the moment I switched it to the old static IP address it started throwing that internal error too, while the old PC - now on dynamic address - can now RDP to the server without any issue.

If I look into the server's Windows Events, I can see that it does receive the connection (for each time I connected there's a bland event saying `Listener RDP-Tcp received a connection`, and no other event)

I tried rebooting both the PC and the server, [changing the MTU](https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/Changing-the-MTU-size-in-Windows-Vista-7-or-8) in both [as suggested here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1272466-remote-desktop-error-an-internal-error-has-occurred) and running a `chkdsk c: /f` [as suggested here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1582180-remote-desktop-connection-an-internal-error-has-occurred), but none of these fixed the issue.

I would really prefer not abandoning this static IP address, and am trying to find out if there's a solution to this issue.

EDIT: I have just found out that I can't reach that server's shared folders either (e.g. \\192.168.2.99 in file explorer), which used to work. Apparently this is not just an issue with RDP.

Comment: This is just an educated guess, but I think there is a client fingerprint / certificate stored on the server that is associated with the IP address. Now, when you use a new computer at the same IP address, you are having a different fingerprint, which makes it close the connection. I don't know any details how Windows works internally, so I cannot give any concrete instructions on how to fix it.

Comment: The point is that I was getting the same error even on the old PC, so I doubt this is the problem (or the main problem)